# Uploading File in WatiN

Tags: watin

1. How do I upload a file using WatiN?
2. Is it possible for this file to reside on a web server (as oppose to it being on user's machine)?

Code snippet is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The file needs to be accessible to the client browser. That means it either needs to be on the client machine or accessible through a share. If you want to store files in a central location, either use a shared folder, or come up with a way to copy the file to the client when you need it.

As for uploading the file, that is going to depend on how you have to do it. If it uses a standard file input tag, it would work like this:

HTML snippet:

```
<form action="upload.asp" method="post">
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
<input type="submit" name="submit_upload">
</form>
```

Code:

```
void UploadFile(string filepath, Browser browser)
{
  FileUpload upload = browser.FileUpload(Find.ByName("uploaded_file"));
  upload.Set(filepath);
  Button submit = browser.Button(Find.ByName("submit_upload"));
  submit.Click();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in the latest IE. Instead, when doing `upload.Set()`, the file selection window opens and nothing happens afterwards.